# How to access node from hook_html_head_alter()?

Tags: 7, hooks

I want to add an `og:url` tag to the `<head>` so that the correct image shows up when my page is shared on Facebook.

I've found the `hook_html_head_alter()` hook which looks like I can add something to the head. I don't see how I can access the node object though when inside this method. I want to check if this page is for a certain Content Type. If it is that type, then look at some of the data on that node to determine which image to put in the `og:url` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drupal alter hooks, the group of hooks including [hook_html_head_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_html_head_alter/7), are not thought to add values, but to alter the values provided by another module. If you need to add a tag to the `<head>` of a node page, you should:

- In a module, implement [hook_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7), check `$view_mode` is not equal to `'teaser'`, and possibly other values for which you cannot provide the tag you want to add. Alternatively you can implement hook_entity_view(), which is called for every defined entity; if you just want to add the tag to nodes, you should rather implement `hook_node_view()`.
  You can also implement [hook_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7), which is invoked every time a node is shown, or `hook_preprocess_page()`, which is invoked for every page, including the page containing the node edit form. In `hook_preprocess_page()`, you need to verify `$variables['node']` is not empty; if it empty, it means the page is not about a node.
  The alternative is implementing [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7), but that hook is not invoked for cached pages.
- In a theme, implement `hook_preprocess_node()`, or `hook_preprocess_page()`.

In all the cases, you need [drupal_add_html_head()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7) to add the tag, and [menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7), when you don't have the node object, which is available in `hook_node_view()`, `hook_preprocess_node()`, and `hook_preprocess_page()`. You would need to call `menu_get_object()` in `hook_init()`, for example.

Notice that `menu_get_object()` called without arguments returns a node object, if the page is about a node, and its path is similar to node/[node ID], or starts with that string; if the page page is, for example, page/node/[node ID] (where page/node/[node ID] is not a path alias), then `menu_get_object()` doesn't return a node object; in the example path I used, you should use `menu_get_object('node', 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question you could use [menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) inside `hook_html_head_alter()` to get the node object, as in `$node = menu_get_object();`.

As for solving the actual problem it would probably be more suitable to use [drupal_add_html_head()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7) and [template_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7):

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if ($node->type == 'sometype') {
    $element = array(
      '#tag' => 'meta',
      '#attributes' => array(
        'property' => 'og:url',
        'content' => 'http://example.com/example',
      ),
    );
    drupal_add_html_head($element, 'og_url');
  }
}
```

Like kiamlaluno pointed out in his answer it's also possible to use some other preprocess/hook functions and you may want to do additional checks (looking at the view mode and page url for example - the [arg()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) function may be useful with the latter) to make sure the tag is only added to the pages you want.